# Rep Got Capped Too Early?

Tags: support, reputation

According to the 'Today' tab I have 172 rep earned today. Yet I have answers that get upvotes that aren't worth anything, and haven't been turned into Community Wikis. 
[Error1 http://chacha102.com/chacha/rep_error2.png](http://chacha102.com/chacha/rep_error2.png)
[Error2 http://chacha102.com/chacha/rep_error.png](http://chacha102.com/chacha/rep_error.png)

Questions in Question:
[PHP - Help building a multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224906/php-help-building-a-multi-dimensional-array/1224914#1224914)
[PHP Array Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224919/php-array-parsing/1224959#1224959)
[PHP Classes: when to use :: vs. ->?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224789/php-classes-when-to-use-vs/1224824#1224824)

And is it possible that this question which I answered before it got migrated screwed with the reputation: [How come I can't enter my password in PuTTY?](https://superuser.com/questions/17630/not-able-to-enter-password-in-putty-exe/17631#17631). I believe it has 3 upvotes when it was migrated .

Comment: And no, I didn't downvote 28 posts.

Comment: I checked Jon's rep tracker (http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=58088&mode=today&showflair=true) and it only shows a gain of 173, so I upvoted you and it didn't change your rep. I'm out of ideas, but I wanted to provide this info in case other people wanted to try to figure it out.

Comment: If a post is deleted, does it still affect the cap? If so, it could be a deleted post somewhere...

Comment: I think I deleted 1 or two posts, but neither with up or down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience this usually happens if something got deleted. For instance, suppose you'd got up to 215 and then had one downvote (putting you on 213). Then an answer with 4 upvotes got deleted. That would reduce your score for the day by 40, but for some reason the rep cap would still be applied.

At the next rep recalc, you won't have received those points in the first place, so (if they were awarded in the same day) you'll regain them from upvotes.

I suspect it's just a case of there being a few different places where rep is stored - totals, total for the day, and rep for the actual answers - and they get slightly out of sync.

Comment: Yeah, that must be it. The migrated question got 3 or 4 upvotes, but is now 'deleted'. Thanks.