# Daily Reputation Limit Bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate or a bug / feature but looking at the following screenshot:

[image: Reputation Cap Bug]
[image: Reputation Cap Bug Update]

**Shouldn't my reputation be 210 and get capped down to 200? Why 192?**

I noticed this after seeing my rep going from 200 to 215 and suddenly it drops back to 192.

SO has some really strange behaviors sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone removed their upvote after you hit your cap, it would have brought it back down.

Chances are, you hit 202 rep through an accepted answer or some other uncapped reputation, and then someone removed an upvote.

Frankly, while it should be easy to explain how you got the reputation you did, due to the capping it is sometimes fairly random how much rep you get for certain answers.

Comment: Thanks, I see how the rep cap can be troublesome. I just got up voted twice again but my rep is still in 192, shouldn't it go as high as 200?

Comment: It might be lagging. If you downvoted a bunch of people, that lowers the cap aswell. (4 Downvotes would make you only be able to have 196 reputation that day)

Comment: Look at this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12008/rep-got-capped-too-early

Comment: I down-voted only one answer today. Can rep points lag?!

Comment: It's weird, but thanks for the tip! =)

Answer (score 1):

If votes or questions/answers with them get removed after you hit the rep limit, the limit stays active, so that new upvotes still won't count. This might lead to a low limit for the day:

[image: rep limit 104]

(This example is caused by an answer to [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106197/how-to-write-a-progam-that-intelligently-picks-powerball-numbers))

Answer (score 1):

If an upvote is removed that affected the rep cap, after you hit the rep cap, your reputation will be adjusted correctly withing 5 minutes as part of [the recent reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).  So even with the rep cap in play, vote deletions will be accounted for.

Comment: Hi Nick, I face the same problem. I reached rep limit 200 but due to one unupvote, my cap for the day is 190 now. As per this post, it should be corrected back to 200 within 5 min? But it's been 5hrs since the unupvote, my cap is still remains 190. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar - It's fixed now (would have been tonight), that's a crazy corner case - I'll see if we can detect it sanely but my guess is not (not worth the cost on every vote check, vs. a daily sync when it does occur).  Will take a look after this conference.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Looks like it worked! Reached 200 now.